# DataTable encrypt / decrypt over web service vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wcf, datatable

We are passing a datatable over a web service.  We would like to encrypt the datatable, send over wcf and then decrypt for use on the other end. What would be the best easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use/require an HTTPS channel, which is already supported by WCF. This is Transport Security. Once could also enable SOAP/WS-Security (or Message Security). See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx. Using either (or both) of these are "standard" and relieve a possibly botched custom implementation. (Key exchange is as vital a task as the encryption itself.)

Comment: As many times as people chide on WCF - and, with good reason, hate consuming it from JavaScript or non-.NET stacks - it really does have its use cases..

Comment: Yes the wcf will already be using https.  I'm asking because we wanted a way to verify that the datatable does not loose any data or become corrupt while transferring. Do you know if this is possible ? is there a way of verifying that the entire datatable gets transferred. Some sort of intergrity check, thats why we were thinking possible encrypting it and decrypting.

Comment: It won't become corrupt accidentally and Transport/Message security mitigates 'non-accidental' tampering. WCF uses HTTP (here) uses TCP - which makes it reliable from top to bottom. Performing an integrity check is a secondary concern to encryption. Search for HMAC, perhaps, especially if such verification is to have a longer lifetime than the request itself. Also note that WS-Security implicitly handles message digests.

Comment: You can calculate its HASH (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) before send it through HTTPS and check it again after receive it in server. Obviously you must send also that number to compare there in server.

Comment: so if i generate the hash value for a dataTable. pass the original datatable and the hash value. then rehash the datatable when it gets there on the server and compare to the original hash value. will they be the same though?